# Mergy multiple PDF files into one PDF file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf

I am developing a rails(3.0) application and the application has to merge pdf files into one.
Some of the pdf files are uploaded from the users and others are generated by the server application using PDFKit (html to pdf).

Converting html to pdf was a breeze but I am not sure how I can merge pdf files into one.
Can you give me some advice on this?

Thanks.

Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can avoid merging PDF files, and instead create the PDF file as you need it, do so. If not, then [PDF::Toolkit](http://pdf-toolkit.rubyforge.org/) should be helpful.